# INSERT a row dynamically in a locale Microsoft Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, odbc

I'd like to insert a row in a table I have in a mdb. I tryed first with an OdbcAdapter but it didn't work. Now I'm trying with this:

This is the string of the command

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO tab_infoap (AP NR, Filiale, AP Device, MAC ddress, IP Address, SSID, Password, Accesso HTTP) " + "VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

For every ? I add a parameter

```
OdbcParameter p1 = new OdbcParameter("p1", OdbcType.VarChar);
p1.Value = "TEST";
```

Then I make a new Odbc command and add all the parameters I created before

```
cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, db);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
[...]
cmd.Parameters.Add(p9);
```

After that, I try to execute the query

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But a 42000 INSERT INTO error rises and I don't know what to do.

What's the best way to manage a db? I can read the entries in the db easely with a reader doing this:

```
OdbcCommandcmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM tab_infoap", db);
OdbcDataReaderreader = null;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{ 
  apInfoItem.APNumber = reader["AP NR"].ToString();
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column names with white spaces should be encased with square brackets eg. `[Column Name]`.
Change your SQL string to this: `([AP NR], Filiale, [AP Device], [MAC ddress], [IP Address], SSID, Password, [Accesso HTTP])`